# How to access global const variable present in one file to different file

Tags: c++

This variable is defined in xyz.cpp

```
const int i = 10;
```

The below main() method is written in abc.cpp

```
void main()
{
    cout<<i; //trying to access 'i' from a different .cpp file
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to declare it `extern` in abc.cpp:

```
extern const int i;
```

**EDIT**: As stated in the comment below, in C++ (unlike C), to give a `const` variable external linkage, you need to declare it es `extern` also in xyz.cpp:

```
extern const int i = 10;
```

Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/357syhfh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure? Since in `xyz.cpp` it's defined as `const` it should have internal linkage by default ([basic.link] ¶3); to give it external linkage (so that it can be accessed via an `extern` declaration) it should be marked as `extern` also in `xyz.cpp`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia my bad, I confused C with C++, I'll edit the answer right now.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to declare it in a header as `const static int i=10;` and include that header in all the `.cpp` that need that constant. This will allow it to be "inlined" by the compiler in every object file, still avoiding ODR violations.

---edit---

Actually, in C++ the `static` is not required, since `const` objects have internal linkage by default. But in C, you have to put that `static` (and in C++ it doesn't hurt).

Why is this better than the `extern` method? Because:

1. it's more idiomatic. In C++ you'll always write integral constants in headers as `const` variables (and that's the very reason why they have internal linkage by default).
2. it's less typing. You just have to write the `const` declaration once, then your constants are just a `#include` away.
3. it (usually) produces more efficient code. The definition of `extern`-declared variables cannot be accessed by the compiler when it is producing the current object module, so it cannot optimize it by putting its actual value as an immediate value in the produced machine code, it cannot eliminate branches that cannot be reached with that value of the constant, ... Sure, cross-module optimization ("link time code generation", "whole program optimization", ...) does exist, but at the moment compilers have more advanced optimizers than linkers.

Answer (score 3):

Add the keyword `extern` in front of it.

Declare it in `abc.cpp` as:

```
extern const int i = 10;
```

`const` variables in C++ have an internal linkage in C++(unlike C). So to be able to use it in another file you have to explicitly declare it as having external linkage.

Comment: in the statement, extern const int i = 10; why it is necessay to give some value (10 in this case)?

Comment: @user1168582: It need not, Since it is a global variable in one of your files, it will be default initialized if you do not initialize it with any specific value.

Comment: It's a mistake. In `abc.cpp` you mustn't give it some value, otherwise it will give you a duplicate definition error at link time. Instead, you must have that definition (with the initialization too) in `xyz.cpp`. Still, the idiomatic way to define constants in C++ is to write them in include files (and that's the reason why `const` objects declared at namespace level have internal linkage by default) - that will usually result also in faster code.

Answer (score 2):

Put this global variable into header and `#include` this header in all .cpp files where you want to use it.

xyz.h:

```
const int i = 10;
```

xyz.cpp:

```
#include "xyz.h"

void main()
{
    cout << i;
}
```

Or if you want to avoid using header for this purpose, you can declare it as `extern const int i = 10;` in xyz.cpp, but then you have to declare this variable in abc.cpp too, so you should write `extern const int i;` at the beginning of abc.cpp in order to use it.

Comment: First of all, I dont want to use .h files.  I have only xyz.cpp in which i have defined a constant variable.  And another abc.cpp, where i want to access this const variable

Comment: There is not a specific reason for not using it in a header file. I am just experimenting.

Comment: Then keyword `extern` is what you are looking for, as it was written here already. I have edited my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The same way as using extern variables. 
In the file xyz.cpp:

```
extern const int i = 333;
```

In the file abc.cpp:

```
extern const int i;
cout << i;
```